# Eclipse PDE, markerAnnotationSpecification - define without icon

Tags: java, eclipse, pde

I am developing an PDE for Eclipse, i have created annotations via markerAnnotationSpecification (see [PDB help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_editors_markerAnnotationSpecification.html)). I need those annotations without icon on left side (where breakpoints are), but problem is that when i do not specify icon parameter for my annotation, it will use default icon from **symbolicIcon** parameter. Currently i am using a bit hacky solution - loading an empty image. Still cursor changes when user targets icon place, which is not desired behavior.

TL;DR; **Is there a way remove (*do not use*) this icon completely?**

Here is one of my specification extension point elements

```
<specification
            annotationType="com.xxx.profiler.editor.highlight.highannotation"
            colorPreferenceKey="covc_h"
            colorPreferenceValue="255,120,120"
            highlightPreferenceKey="covh_h"
            highlightPreferenceValue="true"
            icon="/icons/ph_icon.gif" <!-- empty icon -->
            label="High Coverage"
            overviewRulerPreferenceKey="covr_h"
            overviewRulerPreferenceValue="false"
            presentationLayer="1"
            textPreferenceKey="covt_h"
            textPreferenceValue="false"
            textStylePreferenceKey="covs_h"
            textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
            verticalRulerPreferenceKey="covv_h"
            verticalRulerPreferenceValue="false">
</specification>
```

//EDIT: I found out that this should be done with *verticalRulerPreferenceValue="false"* but for some reason, even that it is disabled in annotations preferences, the image is shown at my annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found the problem. *org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification* was linked to *markerType* via *org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes* plug-in. In this plug-in i (following tutorial) automatically set parameter **super** to some value, which covered my settings in *markerAnnotationSpecification*. After removing inheritance parameter here, everything works as expected.